# need to add managed module to IIS at the server level, but it does not show up in the drop down

Tags: c#, iis, gac, httpmodule

I wrote a custom http module for a website in c# .NET.  If i deploy the website to IIS I can add the module through the 'modules' section by picking the 'add managed module' option if I am looking at just the website level of IIS.  However, I want to add this module to the whole server so that I can select it from the dropdown in 'add managed module' at the server level.  I've looked around and It looks like I might need to install the assembly that contains my module to the GAC (we are in .net 3.5). This causes a lot of problems because we only have an app_code folder in this project and no AssemblyInfo.cs file so I can't figure out how to give the app_code.dll assembly a strong name. Furthermore, it seems like a bad idea to add the app_code dll to the GAC.  So...

1) How can I add my module to the server level of IIS?
2) Can you help me figure out how to get the module registered in the GAC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the module from the web application. You'll need to move the module code into it's own project so that you can compile it as a DLL that you'll then strongname.

Comment: This worked.  I took the class out of the main website project and moved it to its own class library. I used sn.exe to get the .snk file and added that info to AssemblyInfo.cs in the new class library. Compiled it and everything looked good so I used gacutil.exe to add it to the GAC of the server!  Thanks again!!!